# Effect of correlation in matching

Tags: causality, propensity-scores, matching, mahalanobis

What is the effect of correlations among observed covariates or between observed and unobserved covariates on the quality of matching, when matching iss done using

1. Propensity score
2. (Euclidian/Mahalanobis) distance metric

Should one try to remove correlations by using Mahalanobis distance instead of Euclidean distance metric?

Comment: Effect of correlations on what?

Comment: The Mahalanobis distance does not remove correlations between observed and unobserved covariates. Either metric might work; try both and use the one that yields better balance. There is no reason to rely on theory when methods can be safely evaluated on their balancing performance.